# Changing Array Values In Function - Inline Assembly

Tags: c++, arrays, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

So I taught myself x86 Assembly a while back and was just playing around with inline Assembly in C++.

So what I want to do is in a functions parameters, pass in an array, an index ( unsigned int ) and a number. With assembly it will then change the value in that memory location of the array to the passed in value. So the code looks like this.

```
inline void Set( int pArray[], unsigned int pIndex, int pNum ) {
    __asm {
        mov ebx, pIndex
        mov eax, 4
        mul ebx
        mov ebx, pNum

        lea edi, pArray
        mov [ edi + eax ], ebx
    }
}

int main() {
    int myArray[ 5 ] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    Set( myArray, 2, 7 );
    std::cout << myArray[ 2 ] << std::endl;
}
```

So the code should load the start of the array address, get the index and multiply it by 4 so the memory location is moved by that many bytes, and it changes it to the value passed in. However, when I do this, the value stays the same. Why is that? What is going wrong?

Comment: You probably want `mov edi, pArray` otherwise you might be loading the address of your argument variable, not where it is pointing to. You might want to teach yourself using a debugger too :)

Comment: Yup. That was the problem. I wrote this out of a function originally where the array could be accessed in scope of it so it worked then, but when encapsulated in the function it stopped working so that makes a lot of sense why I should have been using "mov" and not "lea". Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

`lea` stands for "Load effective address", your lea puts the address of the argument.  What you mean is `lea edi, [pArray]`

However, there are two more things:
1) You don't have to multiply by four.  You can do `lea edi, [pArray + 4*ebx]`
Since the "scale index byte" addressing mode lets you multiply by 4 and add an immediate address.

2) You are assuming 32 bits.  What computer are you using that in the middle of 2015 is still working in 32 bit mode?

I am rusty on intel syntax assembly.  May I recommend you to learn the integration of assembler and C++ code in GCC?
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html

Comment: For 1, `lea edi, [ pArray + 4 * ebx ]` does not change the value. And for 2, that's a great question. I'm in Visual Studio Professional 2010 and It won't allow me to use 64-bit registers. I did it originally with 64-bit registers but kept getting error C2415.

Comment: There is no need to load the effective address, nor to use the multiply instruction.
Check what the gcc compiler explorer shows:
http://goo.gl/njHPU3
Just use the "scale index byte" addressing like this:
`mov [rdi + rsi * 4], edx`
Where rdi is the array base address in the linux calling convention, rsi is the index parameter and edx is the value